# Code for list elements

Tags: python, selenium

I'm having some problems with with a list.
The code that i need has to do this
I have a list of elements that the code founds by css selector, whe the code has found all the elements,
It has to takes the text from the first element of the list, insert the text in a link, let the broswer look for that link, then return to the initial page where the list is present, look again for the same list, this time the code must take the text of the second element and do the same, therefore, must put the text in a link and look for it, then return it to the initial page ...

The code that i wrote is this

```
segui_css_selector= "._5f5mN.jIbKX.KUBKM.yZn4P"
selector_link_gente_seguita=".FPmhX.notranslate.zsYNt"

while a<50:

    #start the loop

    time.sleep(3)
    segui= driver.find_element_by_css_selector(segui_css_selector)
    time.sleep(1)
    a += 1
    print (a)
    time.sleep (5)
    link=driver.find_element_by_css_selector (selector_link_gente_seguita).text
    print(link)
    driver.get ("https://www.instagram.com/" + link + "/")
    time.sleep(3)
    segui = driver.find_element_by_xpath ("/html/body/span/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/span/span[1]/button")
    segui.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.get ("https://www.instagram.com/" + Pagina + "/")
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//a[@href=''"/' + Pagina + '/followers/''"]').click ()


    time.sleep (5)



a = 0
```

the problem is this, when the code has finished the first cycle, so: it takes the text from the first element, puts it in the link, makes the link search and then returns to the initial page, the code continues to take the text always from the first element.
I do not know how to make it continues the loop by taking the text from different elements each time

This is an example of elements list:

```html
<a class="FPmhX notranslate zsYNt " title="zoe1" href="/zoe1/">A</a>

<a class="FPmhX notranslate zsYNt " title="zoe2" href="/zoe2/">B</a>

<a class="FPmhX notranslate zsYNt " title="zoe3" href="/zoe3/">C</a>

<a class="FPmhX notranslate zsYNt " title="zoe4" href="/zoe4/">D</a>

<a class="FPmhX notranslate zsYNt " title="zoe5" href="/zoe5/">E</a>

<a class="FPmhX notranslate zsYNt " title="zoe6" href="/zoe6/">F</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch multiple elements that match the same css selector you can use the `find_elements_by_css_selector()` method like below. It will find all the web elements that matches the css selector and return a list of those web elements. So, you can iterate over that list:

```
segui_css_selector= "._5f5mN.jIbKX.KUBKM.yZn4P"
selector_link_gente_seguita=".FPmhX.notranslate.zsYNt"
time.sleep(3)
for element in driver.find_elements_css_selector(segui_css_selector):
    time.sleep(5)
    link = element.find_element_by_css_selector (selector_link_gente_seguita).text
    print(link)
    driver.get ("https://www.instagram.com/" + link + "/")
    time.sleep(3)
    segui = driver.find_element_by_xpath ("/html/body/span/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/span/span[1]/button")
    segui.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.get ("https://www.instagram.com/" + Pagina + "/")
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//a[@href=''"/' + Pagina + '/followers/''"]').click ()


    time.sleep (5)
```